# How to add Deeplinking In wordpress to Android Application?

Tags: php, android, ios, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

In My project Website & Application both are live.
So in website, Share post functionality are added using plugin. but when any user share post using their phone and user wants to open this post in their phone and he was installed Android App then we have to show popup message like You have to open this URL in Chrome or You have to open this in Android App.

So any deep linking possible with this scenario ?

I've tried this but not get success.
https://help.branch.io/faq/docs/how-can-i-integrate-the-web-sdk-in-a-wordpress-website

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare in manifest that your `Activity` can open such links by adding proper `intent-filter`

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.yoursite.com" />
    <data android:scheme="https"
          android:host="www.yoursite.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

inside `Activity` in `onCreate` you may try to read clicked link by

```
val action: String? = intent?.action
val uri: Uri? = intent?.data
```

if there is a proper `action` (`VIEW`) and `uri` is pointing on your domain just load your url

doc in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)